# Quickly execute commands without running out of memory

Tags: process, mono, memory-usage

I am writing a .Net application that runs on Mono. It executes and gets the output of several terminal commands every second or so, continuously.

However, after several seconds, it will crash because the output is null.

Upon further inspection, this is due to the process crashing because it ran out of memory, for example:

```
ERROR: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: ApplicationName='upower', CommandLine='-i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0', CurrentDirectory='', Native error= Out of memory
```

Is there a way to rapidly execute the commands while cleaning up the memory used after usage so it doesn't run out of memory?

I am executing the commands like so:

```
 Dim ret As String = ""
 Dim proc As New System.Diagnostics.Process()
 proc.StartInfo.FileName = file 'i.e upower
 proc.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments 'i.e. -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
 proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
 proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
 proc.Start()
 ret = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
 proc.WaitForExit()
 Return ret
```

Running "Mono --version" returns version 3.2.8 if that helps.

I even tried placing `proc.WaitForExit()` before reading the output, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before: `proc.Start()`

Add a handler method. For example:
`process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, a) => Console.WriteLine(a.Data);`

and replace this line:
`ret = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()`

with this:
`process.BeginOutputReadLine();`

---

As an alternative you might also simply try adding only `process.BeginOutputReadLine()` after `ret = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()` in your original code (so only adding one line with the call to BeginOutputReadLine). This should prevent a deadlock on the StandardError stream.

Good luck!

Comment: Right before you posted this, I appended `proc.Close()` right after `proc.WaitForExit()` and it **appears** to be working, but I am still timing it. What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: I don't know actually, but it doesn't sound completely right. It is because the output to the console must normally be read from the buffer otherwise the process will stop because the buffer is full. Also, I expect ret will not have any value of the console output? Would expect it to be empty.